# HOw to get RadList SelectedItems into collection using MVVM

Tags: listbox

Hi Friends,
                    I am using Teleric RadListbox and have issue with **SelectedItems** as it is readonly and I need the list of selected Items to be collected in a observable collection  and perform further operation on it for this I am using EventTrigger and it fires, but I am unable to pass the command to argument as I am not using MVVM light or other framework and also  I binded the

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=AuSelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

SelectedIndex Property to viewmdoel as above but this doesn't fire everytime I select a new Item and the _auSelectedIndex remains 0 everytime.

```
public void AuditLogSelectionChanged()
    {
            listSelIdx.Add(_auSelectedIndex);
    }
```

Belwo is my RadList code snippet is there any other approach to achive the same i.e. selectedItems in ObservableCollection.

```
<telerik:RadListBox x:Name="RadListBox" Height="120" Grid.Row="3" Margin="10 10 10 10" ItemsSource="{Binding OutputIndexFields, Mode=TwoWay}" IsTextSearchEnabled="{Binding ElementName=IsTextSearchEnabledCheckBox, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"                  TextSearchMode="{Binding ElementName=TextSearchModeComboBox}" SelectionMode="Multiple"  IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=IsEnabledCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}"> 
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=RadTabCtrlAdminSetting}"
                                    EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="LogSelectionChanged"
                                             TargetObject="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=RadTabCtrlAdminSetting}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </telerik:RadListBox>
```

Comment: To further brief my issue it's similar to http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/checked-listbox-does-not-persist-59400.aspx but with out a solution.